# Error on Install of WPF .net Core 3.1 App Deployed to Microsoft Store

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

After install the App from Microsoft Store it doesn't start and no error message. In "Windows EventHandler - Windows logs - Program" I'm getting this error:

Description: A .NET Core application failed.
Application: MyApp.UI.exe
Path: C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\MyCompany.MyApp_1.0.30.0_neutral__xxxxxxxxxxxxx\MyApp.UI\MyApp.UI.exe
Message: Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.UI.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design', version: '3.1.2'
    path: 'lib/netstandard2.0/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.dll'

I don't even reference EntityFrameworkCore.Design.

The App works just fine if Published to folder.

What I have tried:

1. Removed all Package References and added them back again.
2. Deploy with references for Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design even though I should not need need it.
3. Added and removed Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design in "Manage NuGet Packages".
4. Removed and re-added references between Projects.
5. dotnet restore.
6. Uninstalled and re-installed Visual Studio 2019 (For some other reasons too, xaml designer was not working)).
7. Un-loaded Projects and Loaded them back again.
8. Clean Solution - Deleted obj and bin folders - Clean Solution and Rebuild.

[MyApp.UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K23Tf.png)

[MyApp.DataAccess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jx8j7.png)

I would have added .csproj files if I knew how to get formatted properly here...

Have another App in the Microsoft Store with basically the same everything but it works to install and run. The only difference I come across is that it is migrated from .net framework to .net core and uses SQLite instead of SQL server.

Here is parts of MyApp.UI.deps.json that mentions Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design in "...\MyApp.UI\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish":

```
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Analyzers/3.1.2": {},
  "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/3.1.2": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.CSharp": "4.7.0",
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational": "3.1.2"
    }
  },
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools/3.1.2": {
    "dependencies": {
      "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design": "3.1.2"
    }
  },
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design/3.1.2": {
  "type": "package",
  "serviceable": true,
  "sha512": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  "path": "microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design/3.1.2",
  "hashPath": "microsoft.entityframeworkcore.design.3.1.2.nupkg.sha512"
},
```

So it's obviously something that is being added and should be added. It looks just like the app that works. But what goes wrong when creating the app package or uploading it to the Store?

How is MyApp.UI.deps.json created?

Comment: Some new information.
The program is installed and starts if I remove the references to EntityFrameworkCore from the UI project before Deploy. Then it works as it should.
However, there is a problem in Package Manager Consol when running "Add-Migration" and "Update-Database" (Startup Project). Right now, I'm adding the references when I need to do changes to the Database and removing them before Deploy.